# What are good sources for streaming Japanese language television?

Tags: resources

While learning Japanese I'd like to watch some Japanese television, whether it is children's programming, drama, or news.

I've found a few places online that allowed me to stream snippets, but nowhere to watch full shows. Is there a service similar to Hulu that has Japanese programming?

Comment: Hi guys, really stoked that we've got questions and answers coming in off the bat but this question is off topic. Please stick to questions about the language itself. You can take a look at the example on/off topic questions to see concrete examples. Thanks.

Comment: This can be done a community wiki, since even if off topic, it's rather useful.

Comment: So is the scope of this site just "Japanese Language" or is it for "Learning Japanese Language"? StackOverflow is about programming, but there are often discussions revolving resources for learning programming.

Comment: It's related to Japanese learning, which I think keeps the spirit of the site... however, I agree, this should be a community Wiki. Make is a community wiki and the close votes will come off.

Comment: http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1/can-this-site-include-questions-about-resources-one-would-use-to-learn-the-japane

Comment: I'm actually glad this got closed after it was answered. Heh heh.

Comment: This question may be off-topic, but its popularity says something, don't you think?

Comment: @MatthewD: I think that it says that many people do not care the scope of the website.  This is exactly why off-topic questions are closed.  If most users ignore off-topic questions, we do not have to close them to begin with.

Answer (score 14):

http://tvfromjapan.blog.fc2.com/blog-category-21.html

http://wwitv.com/television/106.htm

http://multilingualbooks.com/online-tv-japanese.html

http://beelinetv.com/

http://www.sonymusic.co.jp/?play_vc24&all

http://www.ustream.tv/technology

http://watch.squidtv.net/asia/japan.html

http://tv.atcommons.com/

Comment: Many thanks! The multilingual link gave me shopping channels like QVC - the ultimate "comprehensible input" site.

Answer (score 7):

http://www.viki.com/ has some in a variety of languages, but many in Japanese. The subtitles are likewise available in several languages, sometimes including the transcripted original Japanese. I'm not sure how good the content is though, since I only saw ドラマ which isn't my thing.

They seem to be a legitimate business with VC funding, so I don't think it's a piracy site, which is a plus.

http://www.youtube.com/user/tokyomx is a news channel available on YouTube. The really nice thing is that many of their videos have Closed Captioning in Japanese (click the CC button on the video). So you can read the Japanese as they speak it.